# Como realizar um Where utilizando Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma aplicação web que preciso apresentar uma lista contendo alguns dados, para isso, criei o  `Model: Crm_Analise`:

```
public class Crm_Analise
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cod_item_CRM { get; set; }
    public string TAG { get; set; }
    public string data_creat { get; set; }
    public string modelo { get; set; }

    public int cliente_CRM { get; set; }
}
```

E por `Scaffolding` criei o `Controller` e as `Views`.

Porém, preciso que, seja exibido somente os dados ref. ao cliente logado.
Então estou utilizando `Session` para armazenar o código do cliente.

Ai no `Controller` fiz o seguinte:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        if(Session["cod_cli"] != null)
        {
            db.Crm_Analise.Where(x => x.cliente_CRM == Convert.ToInt32(Session["cod_cli"]));

            return View(await db.Crm_Analise.ToListAsync());
        }
        else
        {
            return Error();
        }
    }
```

Porém, não mudou em nada, continua me trazendo a lista inteira.

Comment: O where está correto. Tentou ver no banco se todos os registros estão para o mesmo usuário?

Comment: @FilipeOliveira sim, já verifiquei e tenho vários registros, para vários usuários diferentes..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Falta atribuir a query filtrada no `ToListAsync()`.

Perceba que o `Where` não altera a coleção original, independentemente se for uma lista, um `IQueryable` ou qualquer outra coisa, ele **retorna** uma nova coleção com elementos que atendam ao predicado.

Ao retornar a *view* usando `db.Crm_Analise.ToListAsync()` você simplesmente está materializando todos os itens do `DbSet` e enviando para a *view*.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    if(Session["cod_cli"] != null)
    {
        var query = db.Crm_Analise.
                       Where(x => x.cliente_CRM == Convert.ToInt32(Session["cod_cli"]));

        return View(await query.ToListAsync());
    }
    else
    {
        return Error();
    }
}
```

Comment: Só tem um erro no lugar de `retorno` é `query`!

Comment: Ótima resposta, explicou perfeitamente.

Comment: Valeu, @JulioBorges. Pela edição também =)

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que vc está executando o Where, mais executa o ToListAsync em todo o DbSet, altere o seu código para:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    if(Session["cod_cli"] != null)
    {
        return View(await db.Crm_Analise.Where(x => x.cliente_CRM == Convert.ToInt32(Session["cod_cli"])).ToListAsync());
    }
    else
    {
        return Error();
    }
}
```